# Jenkins retore NuGet packages in MAC OS

Tags: macos, xamarin, jenkins, xamarin.forms

I do not know how to restore NuGet packages from my Xamarin forms solution on a MacOS machine as it does not run .exe. how to make? Could a step by step be possible?

Execute Shell:

> nuget /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Downloads/NuGet.exe restore MyProject.sln
>   /Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/jenkins8846835388185628663.sh: line 2:
>   nuget: command not found

Comment: On non-Windows systems run it through mono. So it should be `mono nuget.exe <arguments>`

Comment: @GeraldVersluis same line but replace NuGet.exe with mono? Or if the path is different, replace the entire path, I already did this but it does not work.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis put the line and type of complete buildstep please? Here only this does not work in Execute Shell

Comment: `mono /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Downloads/NuGet.exe restore zapConefta.sln` should do the trick

Comment: "mono command not found"... mono should not be some variable, or even be filled with the full path to the mono?

Comment: Do you have Xamarin installed on the Mac? Mono is the cross-platform runtime for .NET and the core of Xamarin. If Xamarin is installed it should be available.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis Yes, i have installed by the Visual Studio for Mac. Read this: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/mono /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Downloads/NuGet.exe restore MyProject.sln
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/tmp/jenkins2517596906618089660.sh: line 2: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/mono: cannot execute binary file.  I think nuget.exe is the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute Shell:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.4.1/bin/nuget restore MyProject.sln
```

I entered the path to my nuget which in the case was this down with the restore command and the solution name. Worked perfectly.